# relación de tabla(um a um), problema con @if & @else - dice que no es un objeto | poner al usuario en varias tablas durante el registro - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

**Resumen del problema:**

Tengo dos tablas: empresas y personalidades, ambas relacionadas por identificación, sin embargo, necesito que el usuario registrado en las empresas también se registre en personalidades, porque obtendré su nombre allí, pero esto no ocurre automáticamente, esto termina exponiendo a aplicación, porque tengo que crear uno por uno manualmente, necesito que los nombres de los usuarios registrados en la tabla de empresas también estén presentes en la tabla de personalidades, correctamente relacionados.

---

Necesito saber si la vista existe o no, porque el nombre del archivo proviene de la base de datos, hice un if para mostrar algo más, si no tiene nada, cuando no existe en la base de datos, dice: **Trying to get property 'index_company' of non-object** (index_company es el nombre de la columna)

Fui a google y vi que en algunos foros dicen que no podía hacerlo de esa manera, porque no es semántico o lo que sea, aunque funciona cuando existe, así que lo cambié a un valor como 0, que es lo que indicaron, la gambiarra funcionó hasta que el valor se incluye en la tabla, luego dio esto: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

**controller**

```
public function searchByName($name)
    {
        $company = Company::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
        $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();
        $home_cp = DB::table('personalities')->select('index_company')->where('name', $name)->first();  

        return view('company.base.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp'));
    }
```

- **lo que hace:** obtenga el nombre de la url (app.com/company/name), luego verifique si hay un usuario con ese nombre, si existe, relaciona las tablas con datos específicos de ese usuario, en este caso el valor de la columna index_company.

**company.base.index**

```
@if (view()->exists("company.base.$home_cp->index_company"))
    {{ view("company.base.$home_cp->index_company", compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }} 
@else
    {{ view('company.base.not_company', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
@endif
```

- lo que hace: tenga en cuenta que index_company se refiere al nombre del archivo. 
  Compruebe si este archivo existe o no, si no existe, necesito detener todo lo que está haciendo laravel y simplemente ejecutar lo que hay dentro de @else

que estoy haciendo mal

si es posible, publique un ejemplo con try catch, no encontré nada al respecto en la documentación, lejos de ser controvertido, no para el propósito que quiero.

Comment: Por favor edita tu título y trata de escribir uno que sea un tanto mas concreto y objetivo del problema que tienes

Comment: título cambiado

Comment: no más, $ home_cp-> index_company devuelve el nombre del archivo, tiene varios archivos en una publicación, ese nombre está en la base de datos, el problema es que @if no funciona como debería

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es el if, el problema es que cuando el nombre la vista no existe en la base de datos Eloquent devuelve `null` en vez de un objeto, por lo cual `$home_cp->index_company` no va a funcionar y aparece el primer error que mencionas.

**Solución**

Hay muchas soluciones para este problema típico, voy a explicar la más sencilla (desde mi punto de vista):

Puedes hacer la verificación sobre el tipo de respuesta que entrega la consulta antes del if:

```
$home_cp = DB::table('personalities')
              ->select('index_company')
              ->whereName($name)
              ->first();

$viewName = is_null($home_cp) ? 'not_company' : $home_cp->index_company;

@if (view()->exists("company.base.$viewName"))
  {{ view("company.base.$viewName", compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
@else
  {{ view('company.base.not_company', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
@endif
```

NOTA: Esta es una implementación básica, con el fin de explicar la solución, pero se podría mejorar la verificación inicial, la forma como se llama la vista, entre otras.

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, estaba horas detrás de una solución para eso, ¡gracias!